# Using an ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice in a split/aggregate integration flow

Tags: spring-integration, spring-integration-dsl

I'm looking to implement an integration flow where at some point a split/aggregate writes a bunch of files, returning true or false if an exception occurred in writing one of the files.

It works fine when all files are written without error, I get a list full of `true`s and can validate my business logic.
I've tried to use a `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` to get a `false` when writing one the files failed (regardless of the details of the failure), to no avail:

```
@Bean
public IntegrationFlow mainFlow() {
    return IntegrationFlows.from(...)
            ...
            .split()
            .<MyClass, Boolean>route(pp -> pp.getPattern == null,
                                mm -> mm.subFlowMapping(true, aSubflow()))
                                        .subFlowMapping(false, anotherSubflow()))                
            // the following line works when I don't use an advice, but does not handle exceptions from above
            //.handle((p, h) -> true)
            .aggregate()
            .<List<Boolean>>handle((p, h) -> p.stream().allMatch(b -> b))
            ...
           .get();
}

public IntegrationFlow aSubflow() {
    return f -> f.handle(Files.outboundGateway(...),
                    c -> c.advice(fileSystemAdvice()));
}

@Bean
public Advice advice() {
    var advice = new ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice();
    
    advice.setSuccessChannelName("filesystemSuccess.input");
    advice.setOnSuccessExpressionString("payload + ' was successful'");
    
    advice.setFailureChannelName("filesystemFailure.input");
    advice.setOnFailureExpressionString("payload + ' failed'");
    advice.setTrapException(true);

    return advice;
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow success() {
    // logging works fine, but that's not what I want
    //return f -> f.handle(System.out::println);

    return f -> f.handle((p, h) -> true);
}

@Bean
public IntegrationFlow failure() {
    // logging works fine
    //return f -> f.handle(System.out::println);
    return f -> f.handle((p, h) -> false);
}
```

With this configuration, I get the a DestinationResolutionException `no output-channel or replyChannel header available`.

What's the correct way to branch the outbound of the success/failure flows back to the split/aggregate flow (just before the aggregate)?

UPDATE:

I also tried to use a gateway as mentioned in the [documentation](https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/reference/html/dsl.html#java-dsl-subflows) (the `splitRouteAggregate()` example), but still get the same exception.

UPDATE #2

Here is a minimal failing example: no route, no subflow, just moving a file:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Bean
    public IntegrationFlow myFlow() {
        return IntegrationFlows
                .from(Files.inboundAdapter(new File("./")).patternFilter("dummy.txt")
                           .autoCreateDirectory(true).recursive(false)
                           .useWatchService(true).watchEvents(FileReadingMessageSource.WatchEventType.CREATE))
                .handle(Files.outboundGateway(new File("./out"))
                             .deleteSourceFiles(true)
                             .fileExistsMode(FileExistsMode.REPLACE)
                             .autoCreateDirectory(false),
                        c -> c.advice(advice())
                )
                .<Object, Boolean>transform(p -> !Boolean.FALSE.equals(p))
                .log(LoggingHandler.Level.INFO, m -> m.getHeaders().getId() + ": " + m.getPayload())
                .get();
    }
    
    @Bean
    public Advice advice() {
        var advice = new ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice();
        advice.setOnFailureExpressionString("false");

        return advice;
    }
    
}
```

Create the `out` directory at the root of the project, run the project, and then create a `dummy.txt` at the root of the project, it works fine (though I get two lines of log and not one as I expected).

```
2022-09-16 23:55:23.678  INFO 21564 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : 1d253af9-625a-3745-edbb-0438224a9163: true
2022-09-16 23:55:23.700  INFO 21564 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : 9d2486fc-f776-a5c7-fb21-f16b9ced3094: true
```

Now, create the `out` directory at the root of the project, run the project, rmdir the `out` directory, and then create a `dummy.txt` at the root of the project, to force an IllegalArgumentException when trying to write the file. I don't get a `false` payload, the workflow is interrupted by the exception.

```
    2022-09-17 21:19:00.895 ERROR 14548 --- [   scheduling-1] o.s.integration.handler.LoggingHandler   : org.springframework.messaging.MessageHandlingException: error occurred in message handler [bean 'myFlow.file:outbound-gateway#0' for component 'myFlow.org.springframework.integration.config.ConsumerEndpointFactoryBean#0'; defined in: 'integrationtest.Application'; from source: 'bean method myFlow']; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Destination directory [.\out] does not exist., failedMessage=GenericMessage [payload=C:\Users\*****\Dev\ldd\so73745736\.\dummy.txt, headers={file_originalFile=C:\Users\*****\Dev\ldd\so73745736\.\dummy.txt, id=909a6ffe-6598-da35-33ff-90ebb9c68d67, file_name=dummy.txt, file_relativePath=dummy.txt, timestamp=1663442340858}]
        at org.springframework.integration.support.utils.IntegrationUtils.wrapInHandlingExceptionIfNecessary(IntegrationUtils.java:191)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:65)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133)
        at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:317)
        at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:272)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
        at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.SourcePollingChannelAdapter.handleMessage(SourcePollingChannelAdapter.java:196)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.messageReceived(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:475)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.doPoll(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:461)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.pollForMessage(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:413)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.lambda$createPoller$4(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:348)
        at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.lambda$execute$0(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:57)
        at org.springframework.core.task.SyncTaskExecutor.execute(SyncTaskExecutor.java:50)
        at org.springframework.integration.util.ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.execute(ErrorHandlingTaskExecutor.java:55)
        at org.springframework.integration.endpoint.AbstractPollingEndpoint.lambda$createPoller$5(AbstractPollingEndpoint.java:341)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
        at org.springframework.scheduling.concurrent.ReschedulingRunnable.run(ReschedulingRunnable.java:95)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:304)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
        at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
        at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Destination directory [.\out] does not exist.
        at org.springframework.util.Assert.isTrue(Assert.java:139)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.FileWritingMessageHandler.validateDestinationDirectory(FileWritingMessageHandler.java:496)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.FileWritingMessageHandler.evaluateDestinationDirectoryExpression(FileWritingMessageHandler.java:884)
        at org.springframework.integration.file.FileWritingMessageHandler.handleRequestMessage(FileWritingMessageHandler.java:510)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler$AdvisedRequestHandler.handleRequestMessage(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:208)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
        at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
        at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
        at org.springframework.aop.support.AopUtils.invokeJoinpointUsingReflection(AopUtils.java:344)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.invokeJoinpoint(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:198)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:163)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice$CallbackImpl.execute(AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice.java:151)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice.doInvoke(ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice.java:215)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.advice.AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice.invoke(AbstractRequestHandlerAdvice.java:67)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.ReflectiveMethodInvocation.proceed(ReflectiveMethodInvocation.java:186)
        at org.springframework.aop.framework.JdkDynamicAopProxy.invoke(JdkDynamicAopProxy.java:215)
        at jdk.proxy2/jdk.proxy2.$Proxy46.handleRequestMessage(Unknown Source)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.doInvokeAdvisedRequestHandler(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:155)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(AbstractReplyProducingMessageHandler.java:139)
        at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:56)
        ... 27 more
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The logic of the `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` is like this:

```
@Override
protected Object doInvoke(ExecutionCallback callback, Object target, Message<?> message) {
    try {
        Object result = callback.execute();
        if (this.onSuccessExpression != null) {
            evaluateSuccessExpression(message);
        }
        return result;
    }
    catch (RuntimeException e) {
        Exception actualException = unwrapExceptionIfNecessary(e);
        if (this.onFailureExpression != null) {
            Object evalResult = evaluateFailureExpression(message, actualException);
            if (this.returnFailureExpressionResult) {
                return evalResult;
            }
        }
        if (!this.trapException) {
            if (e instanceof ThrowableHolderException) { // NOSONAR
                throw (ThrowableHolderException) e;
            }
            else {
                throw new ThrowableHolderException(actualException); // NOSONAR lost stack trace
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

So, if `callback.execute()` is OK, we try to call an `onSuccessExpression` (if any) and still return the result of the `callback.execute()`. Looks like in your case it is whatever an HTTP call replies. I don't think we need this `onSuccessExpression` to return just `true`. We can do that a bit later with a `transform()`. Stay tuned.

If `callback.execute()` fails, we call `onFailureExpression`, which in your case could be as simple as: `setOnFailureExpressionString("false")`.

Therefore your advice should be configured like this:

```
@Bean
public Advice advice() {
    var advice = new ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice();
    advice.setOnFailureExpressionString("false"); 
    advice.setReturnFailureExpressionResult(true);
    return advice;
}
```

Now, after that `Http.outboundGateway()` and before an aggregator, you have to add just this:

```
.<Object, Boolean>transform(p -> !Boolean.FALSE.equals(p))
```

Comment: In this case it's a File (not HTTP) outbound gateway. I tried your suggestion for the advice bean and the transform, to no avail: it makes no difference with or without the advice, when the outbound gateway, the workflow is completely interrupted by the Exception. If I wrap the subflow in a gateway as mentioned in the update, I get `Reply message received but the receiving thread has exited due to an exception while sending the request message...`

Comment: Can you, please, modify your code with an actual config and advice I've suggested you to have? We don't know what is that `fileSystemAdvice` at the moment. And, please, share a stack trace if you think that this advice doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, fileSystemAdvice was just a bad copy/paste of my original code. I'm currently setting up a minimal reproducible example.

Comment: Please see update#2

Comment: Any chances that you can give us a link for the project to reproduce ?

Comment: Can we see more stack trace though ? I some how gave felling this specific error for the target dir has nothing to do with the message and therefore that advice .

Comment: Here is a link to the source code (a spring boot project build with maven): https://github.com/choda/so73745736. I'll add the full stack trace right now.

Comment: Sorry, the `advice.setReturnFailureExpressionResult(true);` has to be set as well. By default `ExpressionEvaluatingRequestHandlerAdvice` doesn't care about failure expression result.